# Kafka and Azure EventHub - timeout exception when heavy load

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, debezium

Hey Guys.

I am struggling with issue that I have when connecting Kafka to Azure EventHub.
Our setup is Kafka + Debezium(which is tracking changes from PostgreSQL DB) + Azure EventHub(Standard tier).
Everything seems to be working fine until heavy load is being introduced during initial database replication. After ~1 hour of data replication we hit an error in kafka-connect log and replication stops working:

```
[2022-05-18 11:21:08,464] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81108 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
```

Seems like our Kafka broker is losing connection with EventHub for some reason. We tried to introduce some settings that is recommended by Microsoft but seems that nothing is helping...

Some of our relevant kafka settings

```
connections.max.idle.ms=200000
metadata.max.age.ms=200000
producer.request.timeout.ms=120000
producer.max.request.size=1000000
producer.metadata.max.idle.ms=180000
producer.linger.ms=10000
producer.retries=10
producer.delivery.timeout.ms=1300000
producer.buffer.memory=2097152
consumer.request.timeout.ms=60000
```

Below is more complete log with sequence of events:

```
...
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,036] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Metrics registered (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:102)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,037] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Context created (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:105)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,039] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Found previous incomplete snapshot (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.snapshot.InitialSnapshotter:38)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,039] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] According to the connector configuration data will be snapshotted (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresSnapshotChangeEventSource:62)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,040] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 1 - Preparing (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:87)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,040] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Previous snapshot was cancelled before completion; a new snapshot will be taken. (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:90)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,242] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 2 - Determining captured tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:96)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,260] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 3 - Locking captured tables [ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions, ewl_cmd.ewl_operations, ewl_cmd.ewl_action_types, ewl_cmd.ewl_calling_channels, ewl_cmd.ewl_external_systems, ewl_cmd.ewl_profile_data, ewl_cmd.ewl_wallets, ewl_cmd.ewl_currency, ewl_cmd.ewl_macro_types, ewl_cmd.ewl_oper_oper_search_groups, ewl_cmd.ewl_operation_groups, ewl_cmd.ewl_operation_types, ewl_cmd.ewl_phases, ewl_cmd.ewl_pocket_group, ewl_cmd.ewl_pocket_type_brand_partner, ewl_cmd.ewl_pocket_types, ewl_cmd.ewl_pockets, ewl_cmd.ewl_profile_data_status, ewl_cmd.ewl_profile_data_types, ewl_cmd.ewl_status] (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:103)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,260] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 4 - Determining snapshot offset (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:109)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,260] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Creating initial offset context (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresSnapshotChangeEventSource:231)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,266] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Read xlogStart at 'LSN{27/5A8ABE20}' from transaction '8994616' (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresSnapshotChangeEventSource:234)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,269] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Read xlogStart at 'LSN{27/5A8ABE20}' from transaction '8994616' (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresSnapshotChangeEventSource:144)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,269] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 5 - Reading structure of captured tables (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:112)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,269] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Reading structure of schema 'ewldb' (io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresSnapshotChangeEventSource:190)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,517] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 6 - Persisting schema history (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:116)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,517] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot step 7 - Snapshotting data (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:128)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,524] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshotting contents of 20 tables while still in transaction (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:298)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,524] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Exporting data from table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' (1 of 20 tables) (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:334)
[2022-05-18 10:26:25,526] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      For table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' using select statement: 'SELECT "transaction_id", "transaction_ref_id", "wallet_id", "pocket_id", "external_system_id", "operation_id", "phase_id", "txt_gamecard_number", "txt_trans_ext_id", "txt_digest", "flg_served", "transaction_day", "date_transaction", "txt_caller_client", "num_calling_channel", "txt_cause", "request_parameter_firm", "associated_transaction_ref_id", "exchange_user_rate", "amount_user_exchange", "currency_transaction", "amount_transaction", "exchange_rate_wallet", "amount_wallet_exchange", "account_balance", "available_balance", "gns_transaction_id", "external_transaction_date", "date_transaction_utc" FROM "ewl_cmd"."ewl_transactions"' (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:342)
[2022-05-18 10:26:26,045] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] The task will send records to topic 'ewldb' for the first time. Checking whether topic exists (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:419)
[2022-05-18 10:26:26,153] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Creating topic 'ewldb' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:428)
[2022-05-18 10:26:27,676] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Created topic (name=ewldb, numPartitions=25, replicationFactor=1, replicasAssignments=null, configs={compression.type=lz4, cleanup.policy=compact}) on brokers at dragonflyapl1-event-hub-kafka.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin:389)
[2022-05-18 10:26:27,677] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Created topic '(name=ewldb, numPartitions=25, replicationFactor=1, replicasAssignments=null, configs={compression.type=lz4, cleanup.policy=compact})' using creation group TopicCreationGroup{name='default', inclusionPattern=.*, exclusionPattern=, numPartitions=25, replicationFactor=1, otherConfigs={compression.type=lz4, cleanup.policy=compact}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:436)
[2022-05-18 10:26:30,723] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] 500 records sent during previous 00:00:06.127, last recorded offset: {last_snapshot_record=false, lsn=169022766624, txId=8994616, ts_usec=1652869586237000, snapshot=true} (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:182)
[2022-05-18 10:26:35,877] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 3996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:00:10.353 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:26:40,257] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] 500 records sent during previous 00:00:09.534, last recorded offset: {last_snapshot_record=false, lsn=169022766624, txId=8994616, ts_usec=1652869597677000, snapshot=true} (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:182)
[2022-05-18 10:26:46,132] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 7496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:00:20.608 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:26:57,237] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 11996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:00:31.713 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:27:00,572] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] 500 records sent during previous 00:00:20.314, last recorded offset: {last_snapshot_record=false, lsn=169022766624, txId=8994616, ts_usec=1652869617256000, snapshot=true} (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:182)
[2022-05-18 10:27:07,920] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 15496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:00:42.396 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:27:18,871] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 18496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:00:53.347 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:27:24,660] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} flushing 242 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-05-18 10:27:30,249] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 22996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:01:04.725 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:27:40,545] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] 500 records sent during previous 00:00:39.974, last recorded offset: {last_snapshot_record=false, lsn=169022766624, txId=8994616, ts_usec=1652869657214000, snapshot=true} (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:182)
[2022-05-18 10:27:40,545] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 26496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:01:15.021 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:27:51,673] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 29996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:01:26.149 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:28:02,265] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 33496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:01:36.741 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:28:12,657] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 36996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:01:47.133 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 10:28:22,911] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 40996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:01:57.387 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)

... lot of similar messages until ...

[2022-05-18 11:20:36,787] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 3745496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:54:11.263 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 11:20:46,995] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 3758996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:54:21.471 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 11:20:57,142] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 3770496 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:54:31.618 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 11:21:04,062] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} flushing 242 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-05-18 11:21:07,540] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0]      Exported 3781996 records for table 'ewl_cmd.ewl_transactions' after 00:54:42.016 (io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource:370)
[2022-05-18 11:21:08,464] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81108 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:08,593] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81112 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (8 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:08,722] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81118 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (7 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:08,843] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81124 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (6 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:08,964] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81128 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (5 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,095] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81131 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (4 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,253] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81136 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (3 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,412] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81141 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,541] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81146 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,671] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81152 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,806] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} failed to send record to ewldb:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:372)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,807] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} flushing 202 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,830] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81156 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:09,949] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81162 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (8 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,058] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81167 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (7 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,162] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81168 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (6 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,267] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81169 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (5 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,371] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81170 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (4 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,475] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81171 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (3 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,580] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81172 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,689] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81173 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,797] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 81174 on topic-partition ewldb-19, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: REQUEST_TIMED_OUT (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender:616)
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,901] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} failed to send record to ewldb:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:372)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
[2022-05-18 11:21:10,901] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} failed to send record to ewldb:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:372)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.

... multiple retries until ...

[2022-05-18 11:21:14,808] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:193)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unrecoverable exception from producer send callback
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.maybeThrowProducerSendException(WorkerSourceTask.java:284)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:338)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:256)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:241)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.

...

[2022-05-18 11:21:51,285] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} failed to send record to ewldb:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:372)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
[2022-05-18 11:21:51,285] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} failed to send record to ewldb:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:372)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
[2022-05-18 11:22:05,509] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} flushing 79 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-05-18 11:22:10,510] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 79 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:512)
[2022-05-18 11:22:10,510] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:113)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,808] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Coordinator didn't stop in the expected time, shutting down executor now (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:207)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,811] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot was interrupted before completion (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource:80)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,812] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Snapshot - Final stage (io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource:88)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,812] WARN [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Change event source executor was interrupted (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator:112)
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.doEnqueue(ChangeEventQueue.java:204)
        at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.enqueue(ChangeEventQueue.java:169)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher$BufferingSnapshotChangeRecordReceiver.changeRecord(EventDispatcher.java:443)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher$1.changeRecord(EventDispatcher.java:173)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.emitReadRecord(RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.java:89)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.emitChangeRecords(RelationalChangeRecordEmitter.java:49)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher.dispatchSnapshotEvent(EventDispatcher.java:162)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.createDataEventsForTable(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:380)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.createDataEvents(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:309)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.doExecute(RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:129)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:76)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.doSnapshot(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:153)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:135)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:108)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,812] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Connected metrics set to 'false' (io.debezium.pipeline.metrics.StreamingChangeEventSourceMetrics:70)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,815] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:965)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,817] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Connection gracefully closed (io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection:965)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,818] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1208)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,821] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:659)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,821] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:663)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,821] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:669)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,821] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] App info kafka.producer for connector-producer-dbz-ewldb-connector-0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,822] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] App info kafka.admin.client for connector-adminclient-dbz-ewldb-connector-0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,823] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:659)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,824] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:663)
[2022-05-18 11:22:44,824] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0] Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:669)
[2022-05-18 11:23:10,510] INFO [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} flushing 79 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:505)
[2022-05-18 11:23:15,510] ERROR [dbz-ewldb-connector|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=dbz-ewldb-connector-0} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 79 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:512)
```

Please give me any suggestions as I am out of ideas and close to abandon this solution (Kafka + EventHub)

Best Regards

Comment: How much is the heavy load that starts causing timeouts ? is it consistent or are there times when timeouts don't occur ? 
When timeouts happen,  are seeing those from both producer and consumer or just producer ?  any chance you can try the same load with a premium event hub just for testing and then let me know what happens ?

Comment: @Jdresc - Seems that issue is always after processing ~4700000 records. On EventHub graphs it is ~35GB of data